# Detect touch event in CALayer's coordinate system

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, layer, coordinate-systems

I have controller where are randomly falling a lot of pictures using `CAKeyframeAnimation` and I should crop this images by touching track, 
any animations using `CALayer` for present the animated image, and I am trying to detect touch event inner this layer using `[layer presentationLayer]`.

The problem is - for cropping this image I should create paths from my touching tracker segment and layer, I don't figure out yet how I can create this paths but the question here is how detect this touch point in falling `CALayer` coordinate system, attached picture more informative.

Any ideas?

[image: Explanation pic.]

For detecting touch point in layer related with controller coordinate system I am using this code:

```
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches :(CGPoint) movingPoint :(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSArray *layers = [[contextView layer] sublayers];
    for (CALayer *layer in layers) {
            CGRect imageRect = [[layer presentationLayer] frame];
            if(CGRectContainsPoint(imageRect, movingPoint)) {
                NSLog(@"Image position - x %f y %f", movingPoint.x, movingPoint.y);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you likely know, the point your receive is in the view's coordinate system, which should generally be identical to the view's main layer's coordinate system. (If not, there are still ways to convert it, but unless you've done something weird, it's easier just to rely on the fact that these are the same.)

It's also important to know that once you've started rotating something, its `frame` is undefined. If you think a little bit about how frames work, it should be obvious why this has to be the case (you can't define a diamond using an unrotated rectangle).

We can easily convert from one system to the other using `convertPoint:fromLayer:`. There is no `touchesMoved:movingPoint:` method in iOS, so I'm assuming this is some custom method where you've already worked out the point in your own coordinate system. So you'd want something like:

```
CGPoint pointInLayer = [[layer presentationLayer] convertPoint:movingPoint fromLayer:self.view.layer];
CGRect layerBounds = [[layer presentationLayer] bounds];
if (CGRectContainsPoint(layerBounds, pointInLayer)) {
    // Intersect!
}
```

The bounds are always defined, since they're always in a layer's own coordinate system. So we convert the point into the layer's coordinate system and ask if this point exists in its bounds.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I've miss this fact in a hurry but you show me direction. Thank you!